# grep on --help doesn't work on some commands

Tags: grep

I just wondered why you can't grep on some --help commands.

For example if I use `ifconfig --help | grep unix` it still prints the whole help instead of the line with unix.

But on `grep --help | grep null` it works fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ifconfig` seems to print its help to **stderr** instead of **stdout**. Since piping only passes stdout to the next program, `grep` does not receive the output.

An easy way around that is [redirecting](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-3.html) stderr to stdout. Here's an example on how to do that with `ifconfig`'s help.

`ifconfig --help 2>&1 | grep unix`

produces the wanted output

```
unix (UNIX Domain) inet (DARPA Internet) inet6 (IPv6)
```

**Update**: `2>&1` is what actually redirects (`>`) stderr (`2`) to the same output (`&`) as stdout (`1`). Since usually both stdout and stderr get printed to your terminal, you don't see a difference, but for piping, the actual stream is important.

Comment: Thats interessting. Tank you. But why do some applications write there help to stderr? And what does 2>&1 mean?

Comment: Probably because their coders figured stdout is for actual output of the program, not hints on how to use it. As for the `2>&1`, see update. Also, if an answer solved your problem, please accept it, so other can use it to solve similar issues.

Comment: @Loris1123: it's good to separate errors from normal output: that way you can inform about what happens, and that output (on stderr) is NOT taken as the output from the command (imagine a script that decide `if grep something ce_fichier ; then do THIS ; else do THAT ; fi` : if ce_fichier is not existant, grep can tell so on STDERR (if it did on STDOUT the "if" would see lines, and therefore believe that "something" was indeed in "ce_fichier" !). And adding '--help' to any command will output the help, so it better output this part on stderr...